# Parse javascript source code text and populate two arrays

Tags: php, arrays, regex, parsing, preg-match-all

I am trying to parse some data from a web page using php.
What I have is a html page containing the following lines:

```
var VALUES = new Array();
VALUES[0] = new Array("70","09/11/2020 00.00","7.3","");
VALUES[3] = new Array("73","09/11/2020 00.15","7.5","");
VALUES[6] = new Array("75","09/11/2020 00.30","7.4","");
VALUES[9] = new Array("78","09/11/2020 00.45","7.8","");
VALUES[12] = new Array("81","09/11/2020 01.00","8.1","");
...
```

I need to populate two different arrays (`datetime` and `temp`)

For example, the first line would produce these elements:

```
$datetime[0] = "09/11/2020 00.00";
$temp[0] = 7.3;
```

and so on.

I am really new in doing this with php and I know almost nothing about the pattern syntax. What I am trying to do is something like this:

```
$content=file_get_contents($pageURL);
preg_match('#VALUES[*] = new Array(*)#',$content,$match);
```

Comment: `*` is a qualifier outside of square braces, and it is a literal asterisk inside of square braces.  It never means `any character` in regex. Your question is missing its exact desired output.

Answer (score 1):

- `^` means the start of a line when the `m` pattern modifier is used (at the end of the pattern).
- `\d` is used to match a numeric character.
- `+` means one or more of the preceding expression.
- `*` means zero or more of the preceding expression.
- `(`...`)` is a capture group -- these determine what values are retained in the array of matches.
- I recommend using a negated character class for characters that are unknown between double quotes. `[^"]`

For additional details, I recommend using regex101.com as a sandbox because it spells out everything as you go.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/NmXdi))

```
$content = <<<TEXT
var VALUES = new Array();
VALUES[0] = new Array("70","09/11/2020 00.00","7.3","");
VALUES[3] = new Array("73","09/11/2020 00.15","7.5","");
VALUES[6] = new Array("75","09/11/2020 00.30","7.4","");
VALUES[9] = new Array("78","09/11/2020 00.45","7.8","");
VALUES[12] = new Array("81","09/11/2020 01.00","8.1","");
TEXT;

$datetime = [];
$temp = [];
preg_match_all('~^VALUES\[(\d+)] = new Array\("[^"]*","([^"]*)","([^"]*)"~m', $content, $out, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($out as $m) {
    $datetime[$m[1]] = $m[2];
    $temp[$m[1]] = $m[3];
}

var_export($datetime);
echo "\n---\n";
var_export($temp);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '09/11/2020 00.00',
  3 => '09/11/2020 00.15',
  6 => '09/11/2020 00.30',
  9 => '09/11/2020 00.45',
  12 => '09/11/2020 01.00',
)
---
array (
  0 => '7.3',
  3 => '7.5',
  6 => '7.4',
  9 => '7.8',
  12 => '8.1',
)
```

**If you want to ignore / de-identify the ids from the rows in each row, don't capture the id.**

```
preg_match_all('~^VALUES\[\d+] = new Array\("[^"]*","([^"]*)","([^"]*)"~m', $content, $out, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($out as $m) {
    $datetime[] = $m[1];
    $temp[] = $m[2];
}
```